# How can I avoid shuffling in the following sparkSQL dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Should I use persistence or change the groupBy operation?

```
def joinTests(measurements: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

  val df_joined = df.join(measurements, Seq("part_id"))

  logger.info(df_joined.count + " elements found!")

  val df_keep = df_joined.groupBy(col("name"))
    .agg(countDistinct(col("value")).as("count"))
    .filter(col("count") > 1)
    .select(col("name"))
    .dropDuplicates

  df_joined.join(broadcast(df_keep), Seq("name"))
}
```

Comment: Is the `reduceBy` function available in dataframe too?

Comment: I want to avoid shuffling in the data frame to handle large data, Is there any way I can do it? @ShankarKoirala

Comment: Can you repartition `df` and `measurements` by `part_id` prior to the join?

Comment: yes, we can repartition the df and measurements. @DanW